Subsetting a list of list with lapply in R
I have a df such as:
1_divide  1, 2, 3, 4, 3
2_list c(a, b, z, d, e ...) , c(f, g, h, i, j...), c(a, r, d, g, j...), c(b, v, e, q, h...), c(b, v, e, q, h...)
I want to subset the column list by the number indicated in the same row in the column divide. As a result, a list of list in each cell in the column list.
I've tried looking for such thing as laplly(nest), but had no good answers. Thanks!
